# nunit.framework not found running nunit against .NET Standard 1.4 xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, nunit, .net-standard, visual-studio-mac

I have a .NET Standard 1.4 project used in the place of a PCL in a Xamarin solution. I am trying to add a unit test project.

I have followed the guidelines I could find out there and do the following:

I added a .NET Core 2.0 project referencing my .NET Standard project and installed the following via NuGet:

1. Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.5.0
2. NUnit 3.9.0
3. NUnit3TestAdapter 3.9.0

I added a super simple test with all the NUnit attributes and ran it.

On Visual Studio for Windows, the test runs perfectly using the Resharper test runner. However on **Visual Studio for Mac**, using the built-in runner, I get the **following error**:

> ERROR: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'nunit.framework' or one of its dependencies File name:
>   'nunit.framework'

No amount of Googling or fiddling has helped. Can anyone out there suggest something?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with Visual Studio for Mac 7.3.3. Can you provide a repro project here or on dev community?

Comment: UPDATE: I'm able to reproduce this with a plain vanilla blank solution with only a test project in it. Repros here:

https://github.com/freever/VSMacTestProblemRepro

Comment: This seems to be a problem in VS Mac 7.4. VS Mac 7.3.3 works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your test library cannot be a .NET Standard library. It needs to be netcoreapp or net full framework. So you need to change the target to `netcoreapp2.0` or something like `net461`. Alternatively you can make it multi-target:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

This is due to VSTest and Visual Studio requiring your tests to target a specific platform. This can't be done with a .NET Standard only library.

If you choose to multi-target, your milage may vary in Visual Studio. However, command line tools should work and you should be able to run it very easily with `dotnet test` just pointing it at the `csproj` file for the unit tests.

This is also documented in the NUnit documentation: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard

These limitations do not change if you change to other frameworks like Xunit.

Comment: The OP specifically stated `I added a .NET Core 2.0 project referencing my .NET Standard project`. The test library clearly isn't a .NET Standard project. If it were, it wouldn't run at all on Windows, either.

Comment: @NightOwl888 is correct: my application code is .NET Standard 1.4, while my test code is .NET Core 2.0, as specified in the documentation: "Your test assemblies must also be .NET Core or .NET 4.x, not .NET Standard."

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in VS Mac 7.3.4 beta, which MS is fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Do try by loading nunit.framework assembly manually and referencing it to the test project.